# Awaiting for a for loop to end to continue function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, ecmascript-6

i have one question! I want the function **getMealSummary**() to return after the **for loop** has finished already finished (I didnt include the return key because the function is very big and i just had a doubt in this section).

How can I do it with async/await or promises?

Thanks

```
    export const getMealMicroSummaryHelper = async function getMealSummary(array, populatedFoods, customMeasurements, isRecipe,expertId){
  var [totalZinc, totalCalcium,totalAlphaCarotene,totalBetaCarotene,totalCholine,totalCopper,totalBetaCrypto,totalFluoride,totalVitaminB9,totalIron,
    totalLutein,totalLycopene,totalMagnesium,totalManganese,totalNiacin,totalVitaminB5,totalPhosphorus,totalPotassium,totalRetinol,totalRiboflavin,
    totalSelenium,totalSodium,totalTheobromine,totalVitaminA,totalVitaminB12,totalVitaminB6,totalVitaminC,totalVitaminD,totalVitaminD2,totalVitaminD3,
    totalVitaminE,totalThiamin] = [0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

  let recipesArray = []

  for(let i = 0; i < populatedFoods.length; i++){
       if(populatedFoods[i].foodType === 4){
            await apiCall("get",`/api/experts/${expertId}/recipes/${populatedFoods[i]._id}`)
          .then(recipe =>{
            recipesArray.push(recipe)
          })
          .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
        }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: You most probably need [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all): takes many promises, and returns a new one that will be resolved once all the input ones are resolved.

Comment: The code you have already "waits". Since it's an async function it returns a promise that resolves after the loop. You should add a `return recipesArray`.

Comment: Is this really the _minimum_ amount of code you need to show to allow us to understand your problem?  Surely we can drop some of that code and still get your question answered.  I'm sure we can at least reduce our totalSodium intake here.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for this like:

```
async function getMealSummary(array, populatedFoods, customMeasurements, isRecipe, expertId) {
   try {

      let recipesArray = await Promise.all(
         populatedFoods.map(async populatedFoods => {
            if (populatedFoods[i].foodType === 4) {
               let recipe = await apiCall("get", `/api/experts/${expertId}/recipes/${populatedFoods[i]._id}`)
               return recipe;
            }
         })
      )

   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
   }
}
```

This is just a simple version to give you a basic idea. I have not included all the variables that you have declared above `recipesArray`. Those will need to be included as needed.